# VB6 with a .NET Library

Tags: .net, vb6, compatibility

I have an application written in VB6, and I need to use a library written in .NET. Is there any way to use the library on my application?

Thanks

Comment: I think if the .NET-library exports its interface as COM-interface, it should be possible. Otherwise it's gonna be hard. But I'm not an COM-export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Do you have control over the .NET library?

If so, you can modify your library so that it can be registered as a COM component. You can then utilize the COM component from VB6.

You can follow this CodeProject tutorial for step by step directions on creating a COM component in .NET, registering it, and then calling it from VB6:

[Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx)

Comment: That means if I don't have a control over the library, I won't be able to do it, right?

Comment: @Sahs - Yes, if you don't have the ability to expose the .Net library to COM yourself and you can't get the owner to do it then you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks, another question, how do I decide if I have the ability to expose. This is a third party library, and I have only its dll's. Sorry, I'm new to this .Net - COM things.

Comment: @sahs - If you don't have direct access to the library, you do have the option of wrapping the calls you need in your own assembly and exposing THAT through COM.

Comment: +1 Here's an MSDN article that demonstrates wrapping .Net libraries so they can be used from VB6. It actually demonstrates wrapping native .Net framework objects, but the principle is the same. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719105(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

See [How to call a Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 assembly from Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248) and C[alling .Net Classes from Visual Basic 6](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Calling-Net-Classes-from-Visual-Basic-6/) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the .Net library to COM...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c6747